# Question Regarding Tweepy Username Request

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

When my customers authorize for my application and I receive their oauth token etc. Is there any way to make it so I receive their username as well I'm not sure how to request for that. So I can know which of my customers authorized.

I was trying to request for it but keep getting internal server errors.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.